# How do I install Android Studio SDK Packages offline on windows?

Tags: android-studio, installation, android-sdk-manager

I have to install android studio on around 50 PC's running either Windows 7 or Windows 8.1.

I managed to download and install Android Studio (android-studio-bundle-141.2135290-windows.exe) from here:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

However I also need to install all packages available on the Android SDK manager as well. With a 512kbps internet connection, it would take several months to download these packages *separately* on each PC. To add to the problem, half of these PC's are not even connected to the internet. Is there anyway to download these packages manually and install them offline via the SDK Manager? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy Android Studio and the Android SDK, just copy and paste the android SDK directory to the same default location on the other computers you want to install the studio on.

Then, install Android Studio and set the path variable in the studio settings to the same directory where you copied the SDK (just in case copying to the default location did not work).

The studio will work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

full offline android sdk from official sdk manager

instruction

1- extract the archive

2- in android studio go to setting--> sdk --> set sdk folder to extracted folder 
enjoyy

download link:
Full Android SDK For Android Studio x64 [android 6 marshmallow update

http://torcache.net/torrent/FE1825CB8BB20454A6AC909C0A5193A4F8F5DA09/%5BTorrentKickass.space%5Dfull.android.sdk.for.android.studio.x64.android.6.marshmallow.update.bzhar93.torrent